# AngularUI Router + Ionic - routing works in browser, but not within Ionic View?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have the most simple little Ionic App that works as expected when run in the browser using `ionic serve`.

However, when the app is run in Ionic View ([view.ionic.io](http://view.ionic.io/)), the routing appears to be failing (the `index.html` is loaded, but nothing within `<div ui-view=""></div>` is loaded. This is done using `ionic upload`.

My simple `index.html` looks like:

```
  <body ng-app="app">
      my app!
      <div ui-view=""></div>
  </body>
```

My `app.js` contains:

```
angular
    .module("app", [
        "ionic",
        "ngCordova",
        "ui.router"
    ])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state("splash", {
            url: "/splash",
            templateUrl: "components/splash/splash.html",
            controller: "SplashController"
        }).state("login", {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "components/login/login.html",
            controller: "LoginController"
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/splash");
    });
```

I have a `SplashController` that has:

```
var SplashController = (function () {
    function SplashController($scope) {
        this.test = null;
        this.scope = null;
        $scope.vm = this;
        this.scope = $scope;
        this.test = "Hello world!";
    }
    SplashController.$inject = ["$scope"];
    return SplashController;
})();
App.SplashController = SplashController;
angular.module("app").controller("SplashController", App.SplashController);
```

And my really boring `splash.html` is:

```
<div class="padding">
    <h4 class="title dark">splash.html</h4>
    <h4 class="title dark">{{ vm.test }}</h4>
</div>
```

In my browser (`ionic serve`) I see:

[image: browser screenshot]

And on my device (`ionic upload` / Ionic View app) I just see `my app!`

What am I doing wrong? Is this an issue with the Ionic View app? Has anyone else run into this?

A few other things to note:

- The JavaScript is compiled from TypeScript.
- I had attempted `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` / excluding `ui.router` and the results were the same (works in the browser, but not on the device). I actually dislike the Ionic view animations and prefer to use the standard ui-router, if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this turned out to be the strangest of issues. After further debugging, I realized that not only was the router not working, but Angular was not working at all (`{{ 1 + 1 }}`) displayed literally.

For some reason, the native app did not like my generated JavaScript in a `.tsout` directory. I removed it and placed the same exact file in the same directory as my `index.html`. I'm sure something else was going on behind the scenes, but re-structuring my project files seemed to solve the problem.

**The setup with the error:**

Project structure:

```
/www

    /.tsout
        app.js     // both .tsout and app.js are created through my gulp-typescript task
    /components
    /css
    /img
    /lib
    /typings
    index.html
```

HTML `head`:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="css/ionic.app.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src=".tsout/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

**The solution:**

My project structure *after* I found success both in the browser and on the device:

```
/www
    /components
    /css
    /img
    /lib
    /typings
    index.html
    app.js     // just app.js is created through my gulp-typescript task
```

The `script` tag in the `head` then looks like:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Hope the outcome of this wonkiness can be helpful to someone else!

Comment: Glad you found a solution :), Sometimes `ionic view` fails silently and I had an issue just by not calling an external javascript with exact name (turns out to be its case sensitive). I reckon to test in `phonegap app` before going to `ionic view` `http://app.phonegap.com/`. Ex: my workflow is, browser -> phonegap app -> xcode/android simulator -> ionic view. Saves lot of time :)